# How to justify (mathematically and physically) the total momentum in many-body physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, momentum, many-body

If we have a many-body sistem and we study the limit with infinite particles (we may decide for example to have a fixed constant density), I am trying to understand how classical mechanics and quantum mechanics justify, from both a mathematical and a physical point of view, the existence of the total momentum defined as $\lim_{N \to + \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} p_i$, where $p_i$ is the momentum (let's say over 3 dimensions) of i-th particle.

My first guess is that usually the system considered is a Gibbs state, and the exponential damping of the total kinetic energy allows to have things well-defined even at this limit, but what about a state which is not a Gibbs state?

Despite the fact that I am more interested on hearing how the total momentum operator in quantum mechanics is described, I would like to know also how the problem is fixed in classical mechanics.

**Edit**

There are two cases that in particular I don't understand how to justify the existence of total momentum operator in the limit with infinite number of particles:

1. Let's assume that the system (either classical or quantum) is not isolated, but there is an external force acting on it such that the total momentum of the system is not constant. In this case, which I understand it is not trivial, I just would like to know if it has ever been discussed or if it has been found how to justify mathematically or physically the existence of the total momentum.
2. The second one is again common to both quantum and classical mechanics. In this case, each particle $i$ has the same momentum $q_i = q$ and with $q \neq 0$. In quantum mechanics, this would mean that the state of the system is $|\phi> = \otimes_{i=1}^{N} |q>$. So the system has a well defined total momentum which is simply Nq. Maybe this case is simpler than the previous one, but it is however not fully clear to me how to explain the existence of the total momentum here as well except in the trivial case where $q=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The total momentum operator *exists* because all superpositions of Hermitian operators are also valid operators. It exists because it is well defined by construction. But there is no problem taking $N \to \infty$.

Basically, in quantum mechanics, the observables form a C*-algebra (kind of a ring) in which the sums and products of observables are all observables. The fact that you sum an infinite number of them doesn't cause any issues, or even show up in any calculation. You just can't measure this operator in practice (or even compute it from adding up the individual momenta in finite time).

But there is nothing "dangerous" about taking the $N \to \infty$ limit on the total momentum, and this is not a practical barrier because we do not talk about measuring the total momentum. It is merely a conserved quantity in systems with translation invariance, which has some definite value, that we can just call $P^{\,}_{\rm tot}$ and not worry about beyond that. Without translation invariance, it is just some quantity that we can't measure in practice. But there is no mathematical obstruction to defining it, and the physical interpretation is really about translation symmetry, when $\sum_{i=1}^N p^{\,}_i = P^{\,}_{\rm tot}$ for all times, so there are no equations of motion to solve.

In both classical and quantum mechanics, if a system has translation invariance, we define the total momentum as the corresponding conserved quantity, and *remove it* from the equations of motion, as it is constant in time. In the classical case, it is a "cyclic" coordinate; in the quantum case, it commutes with the Hamiltonian and therefore has a simultaneous eigenstate (any eigenstate of $H$ is an eigenstate of $P = \sum_{i=1}^N p^{\,}_i$). In either case, the evolution conserves the total momentum. In cases without translation invariance, there is no reason to talk about total momentum, though the operator is still well defined.

I don't think having a Gibbs state is necessary or particularly relevant. Please let me know if I've misunderstood your question in some way!

Comment: Thank you @justaphase! I need a bit to properly digest your answer, but I think to understand your point when there are no problems if the state is traslationally invariant. However, there are two cases where that now came in my mind which trouble me, I will edit my question to be more clear. Please let me know what do you think. Can you please also elaborate a bit more on the existence of the infinite sum of Hermitian operators?